# Java: Using Supplier to pass in values at runtime

Tags: java, functional-programming

The problem I am trying to solve is described in [OO: dependent class needs information from grandparent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366423/oo-dependent-class-needs-information-from-grandparent-class)

```
 import java.util.function.Supplier;

 public class SupplyMe {

     private Supplier<String> supplied;

     public SupplyMe(Supplier<String> supplied) {
         this.supplied = supplied;
     }

     public void printSupplied() {
         System.out.println(supplied.get());
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         String changingStr = "hi";
         Supplier<String> helloStrSupplier = () -> changingStr;

         SupplyMe mySupplyMe = new SupplyMe(helloStrSupplier);

         mySupplyMe.printSupplied();

         changingStr = "hi2";
         mySupplyMe.printSupplied();

     }
 }
```

the following code is throwing

```
SupplyMe.java:18: error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
        Supplier<String> helloStrSupplier = () -> changingStr;
```

What can I do to make Supplier be able to supple the value at runtime?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you *actually* trying to do, and why would you think that changing the value that a `Supplier` supplies will solve it?

Comment: @JacobG. i am trying to solve the problem linked with supplier instead of some another interface (Observer pattern)

Answer (score -1):

i was able to get it work by doing this

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

 public class SupplyMe {

     public static String changingStr = "";
     private Supplier<String> supplied;

     public SupplyMe(Supplier<String> supplied) {
         this.supplied = supplied;
     }

     public void printSupplied() {
         System.out.println(supplied.get());
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         changingStr = "hi";
         //Supplier<String> helloStrSupplier = changingStr;
         Supplier<String> helloStrSupplier = new DynamicSupplier();

         SupplyMe mySupplyMe = new SupplyMe(helloStrSupplier);


         mySupplyMe.printSupplied();


         changingStr = "hi2";
         mySupplyMe.printSupplied();

     }

     static class DynamicSupplier implements Supplier<String> {
         @Override
         public String get() {
             return changingStr;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: There’s no point in creating that extra class `DynamicSupplier`, just to return the value of a `static` field. `Supplier<String> helloStrSupplier = () -> changingStr;` would do as well.